# How could i fix error when i am drawing the network

Tags: python, error-handling, networkx, draw

[errors nx.draw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DahNy.jpg)

I coded python for drawing network. It shown errors as this picture.
Please help me.

Comment: Please review [ask] and [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is fix the last line to plt.show instead of plot.show:

```
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

g1 = nx.petersen_graph()
nx.draw(g1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It shown error. Please see my attached picture. --> 5 nx.draw(g1)

Comment: There must be something wrong with your environment. I ran the code exactly as shown above with no errors and produced the graph shown.

Comment: Can you draw any other graph with networkx on your environment?

Comment: Now i can draw. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome.  Don’t forget to accept the answer.